# WaitForSingleObject gets his semaphore in XP but not in Vista

Tags: c++, concurrency, windows-vista, semaphore

The following code runs perfectly well on my XP SP2 machine, but the call to WaitForSingleObject waits indefinitely when running on my Vista machine:

```
HANDLE ghSemaphore;
ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, "COM_PHILOERTEL_FINA");
if (ghSemaphore == NULL) {
 MessageBoxA(NULL,"Error creating semaphore","ERROR",0);
 return FALSE;
}

MessageBoxA(NULL,"Semaphore created. Waiting for it to be triggered","ERROR",0);
WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, INFINITE);
// got the semaphore, ready to rock

MessageBoxA(NULL,"Got the semaphore, ready to rock!","Notice",0);
```

Here's the thread that releases the semaphore:

```
 ghSemaphore = OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "COM_PHILOERTEL_FINA");
 if (ghSemaphore == NULL) {
  MessageBoxA(NULL,"Failed to open semaphore","ERROR",0);
  return FALSE;
 }

 if (0 == ReleaseSemaphore(ghSemaphore, 1, NULL)) {
  MessageBoxA(NULL,"Plugin was unable to release the semaphore","ERROR",0);
  return FALSE;
 }
```

The named semaphore was a recent addition that didn't do any good. Before that the threads were just sharing ghSemaphore with its anonymous semaphore. No apparent difference. Does anyone have any idea why this binary (compiled on the XP machine in VC6, Express Edition fwiw) wouldn't work in Vista? As I said above, the WaitForSingleObject call is what never finishes.

THanks!

Comment: MSDN says that ReleaseSemaphore() requires SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE security attribute. You are using NULL as the parameter for security attribute in the CreateSemaphore(). Can you try once with this security attribute set?

Comment: @Naveen, once the `OpenSemaphore` succeeds (and it apparently does as the OP would probably notice otherwise), the handle *has* the SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE access right.

Comment: @philo, the code works fine for me on Vista, even when I put the snippets into separate processes. Is there something special about your process or is it a normal unelevated application?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is part of a Filemaker plugin (I know...) and there's quite a lot going on. I've made a small console app to try to isolate the problem, just creating the semaphore, spawning a thread to release the semaphore, and calling WaitForSingleObject. That's executed successfully so far. Luckily I have several hours today to figure this out...will update if I succeed.

Comment: A little more context: the plugin has a function that executes when Filemaker starts. It has another function to be called by users as part of calculated fields. I want to start a server that uses a resource only available to the user function. So the startup function spawns a thread which creates the semaphore and waits for this user-called function to open and release it.

I just tried removing the WaitForSingleResource call as a sanity check, and making sure everything else works (in Vista). And it works fine, so it's definitely the semaphore.

Gonna try Dewfy's mutex suggestion. Can't hurt

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check it right now, but heard about it, so try:
Change first argument of CreateSemaphore from NULL to empty instance of SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES dumy;
dumy.nLength = sizeof(dumy);
dumy.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0;
dumy.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
CreateSemaphore(&dumy, 0, 1, "COM_PHILOERTEL_FINA");
```

By the way named semaphore with lMaximumCount = 1 is fully equivalent of named mutex. So review possibility to use mutex.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! Same behavior with this code added though.

Comment: It looks that @Naveen is right, to call ReleaseSemaphore only SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This was entirely user error. Thanks @Dewfy, @Naveen, and @avakar for your thoughtful responses.

I was sure the user function was being called because I was displaying its result in my Filemaker layout. What I failed to realize is that these return values are cached by default. The function was never being called. Your suggestions were really helpful, because it wasn't until I fully understood what I was doing with my threads and semaphores that I was able to step back and say "hang on, something's not right here".

I'm still grappling with the mystery of why when I removed the semaphore code I was able to access the resource that the user function was supposed to provide, even though that function was not running. But that's a separate issue.

feels GOOD